# Sessions are not started

Tags: php, session, cookies

When a user log in using correct information, sessions should be started and cookies should be set. However it doesn't seem to work, not at all. I have `session_start()` located at the very top of the page but it seems to ignore the `$_SESSION` variable because when I do `var_dump($_SESSION['username'])` it returns `NULL`.

**My code:**

```
$username = $kunaiDB->real_escape_string($_POST["uname"]);
    $password = $kunaiDB->real_escape_string($_POST["pword"]);
    $kunaiLoginQuery = "SELECT * FROM kunai_users WHERE user_name = '".$username."'";
    $kunaiLoginQueryResult = $kunaiDB->query($kunaiLoginQuery);
    $controlhash = $kunaiLoginQueryResult->fetch_assoc(); 
    $db_pw_res = $controlhash["user_pw"];

    if(password_verify($password, $db_pw_res)) {

        $checkBlock = $kunaiDB->query("SELECT * FROM kunai_users WHERE user_name = '".$username."' AND user_locked = '1'");
        if($checkBlock->num_rows >= 1) {
            echo "Your account has been locked by a moderator. If you want it to get lifted please appeal here.";
        } else {

            $userRow = $kunaiLoginQueryResult->fetch_array();

            $dbid = $userRow["user_id"];
            $dbuser = $userRow["user_name"];

            $_SESSION['id'] = $dbid;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
            $activeUser = $_SESSION['username'];

            setcookie('active', $activeUser, time() + 60*60*1);

        }

    } else {

        echo '<div class="loginerror">Incorrect login details!</div>';

    }
```

I get no errors when logging in, even if I use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

At this point I'm lost, I need some help.

Comment: Nowhere do you show a `session_start()` !!!

Comment: `wget -S http://localhost/script.php` to see if it engages at all.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the code snippet is not the entire file.

Comment: Using MySQLi or PDO but not **Prepared Statements**. Looks like someone is too lazy to use something so great.

Comment: I managed to fix it myself. I had to duplicate $kunaiLoginQuery, rename it, re-fetch it so $userRow could get the data. The problem was that $userRow received no data from the query.